# How integrate Bluemix Public Accounts/User in LDAP?

Tags: ldap, ibm-cloud

Is it possible to integrate **Bluemix Public Accounts/User** (means **IBM IDs**) in a **LDAP** of Company User Management?

Reason the ensure on-boarding and off-boarding can be done on a central place inside a company.

Is this topic related to a ibm market place integration possibility?
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZPE3_9.1.1/Platform/LDAP/LDAP_AD_integration_features.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a federated ID.

This ID can be used to sign up for Bluemix only if your company has already worked with IBM to register. Registering a company's domain with IBM enables users to log in to IBM products and services by using their existing company user credentials. Authentication is then handled by your company's identity provider. When you log in to Bluemix with a federated ID, you are prompted to log in through your company's login page. For information about requesting to register your company or organization's domain with IBM, or for more information about the process, see IBMid Enterprise Federation Adoption Guide External link icon. An IBM sponsor, such as an offering advocate or client advocate, is required when you request to register federated IDs.

Link: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/admin/account.html